# BadTockenException in Speech-to-Text popup inside PopupWindow

Tags: android, speech-to-text, android-popupwindow

App crashes when using Built-In speech to text dialog:

Here is how i'm opening the PopupWindow:

```
popupwindow = new PopupWindow(MyActivity.this);
.
.
.
popupwindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

and here is the Logcat:

```
05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@21d21dba is not valid; is your activity running?
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:562)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:272)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1058)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:887)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:851)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.updatePosition(Editor.java:2291)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:2248)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.widget.Editor$SpanController.onSpanAdded(Editor.java:1977)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:981)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendToSpanWatchers(SpannableStringBuilder.java:597)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:519)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:454)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:685)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:197)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:184)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:286)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    05-04 15:27:08.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5645):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Any comments, edits, help and Questions are more than Welcome

Comment: Your log saying that your activity is not running at the time when you are showing this PopupWindow.

Comment: But it is running actually @PankajKumar